# Write a program in C which will print the even numbers and the odd numbers in two different series of array. [Numbers will be inserted by users]

Tags: c

This was the problem I was asked to solve ->
So I wrote the following codes -->
I am running this code using gcc compiler on Windows 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b[a], i;
    //The Max. range to print the odd and even numbers
    printf("Enter a range to print the odd and even numbers-->\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    i--;
    for (i; i <= a; i--)
    {
        printf("The Even numbers are -->\n");
        if (b[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d", b[i]);
        }
        printf("The Odd numbers are -->\n");
        if (b[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            printf("%d", b[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, only the first part of the code has executed. This program to neither taking any input from the user [in the array], neither it is returning any errors.
Can you please help me to get the 'C' code working.

Comment: print the value of a after you read it. It may surprise you.

Comment: 'a' returned the value I entered in it. i.e. - 7

Comment: 1) your second `for` loop should start `i` at zero again 2) your second loop needs to be split into two to print out two lists.

Comment: `i--; for (i; i <= a; i--)` ==> `for (i = 0; i < a; i++)`

Comment: I tried the solution by @Vane but the error was not solved.

Comment: What can I do for the program to enter at least into the first for loop and take the inputs from the user?

Comment: Then print each value of b[i] you read it. Then just keep checking (debugging) each part until you find that part that doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `a` to set the size of your array `b` since `a` does not have a value.
Just declare `b` after you have the value for `a`:

```
int a;
printf("Enter a number-->\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
int b[a];
```

Additionally you have a very weird way of looping through your array.
What speaks against something like this:

```
printf("\nThe Even numbers are -->\n");
for(int i = 0; i<a;i++){
     if(b[i] %2 == 0)
         printf("%d ",b[i]);
}
printf("\nThe Odd numbers are -->\n");
for(int i = 0; i<a;i++){
     if(b[i] %2 != 0)
         printf("%d ",b[i]);
}
```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, i;
    //The Max. range to print the odd and even numbers
    printf("Enter a number-->\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int b[a];
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe Even numbers are -->\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<a;i++){
        if(b[i] %2 == 0)
            printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe Odd numbers are -->\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<a;i++){
        if(b[i] %2 != 0)
            printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this fact - 'You can't use a to set the size of your array b since a does not have a value. Just declare b after you have the value for a'.
I tried your recommendation and declared the array b[a] after taking the value of var. a from user. Still it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Swyamdipta you have to change the reporting loop too.

Comment: @Swyamdipta Did you change your output loop? Yours was broken.

Comment: Yes I made the following changes to the output loop -
```for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("The Even numbers are -->\n");
        if (b[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d", b[i]);
        }
        printf("The Even numbers are -->\n");
        if (b[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            printf("%d", b[i]);
        }
    }```

Comment: @Swyamdipta I added my full code compare it with yours and/or try it out :)